# How to send notifications in flutter

Tags: firebase, push-notification, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an appointment app. It has an admin and a user interface.
I want to add an option to admin interface to send custom text notifications to his users like `"The $salonName won't work on $date!"`. Is it possible via FCM?

Comment: Sure, it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible. I suppose U already have a list of tokens for your users and U are using firebase (can work with any other database).

1. Create a `collection` that will store your `notifications` sent by admin.
2. Create a `cloud function` that is *triggered* when an `item` is added to the collection in 1. In this function send Push notifications to all users (whose tokens U already have)

Et voilà!!

Comment: Ok,so I suppose tokens are userIDs, if yes,I got those. Let's say I have created the function,how will it work in background?

Comment: Tokens are device IDS. The push notifications get sent to the user device (do some searches online on how FCM works). Cloud functions are deployed on firebase and get triggered by events check here: https://link.medium.com/kbUVjYuOQT There’re lots of examples online that can help.

Comment: Oh, I got it, should I create a new collection for tokens,or I can just add them to users collection when he register,and update it when he logs in?

Comment: Whatever way works. Do what feels easy for your requirement and future possible requirements